# How can I let perl interpret a string variable that represents an address

Tags: perl

I want to feed input to a C program with a perl script like this 
 `./cprogram $(perl -e 'print "\xab\xcd\xef";')`.

However, the string must be read from a file. So I get something like this:
`./cprogram $(perl -e 'open FILE, "<myfile.txt"; $file_contents = do { local $/; <FILE> }; print $file_contents'`. However, now perl interprets the string as the string `"\xab\xcd\xef"`, and I want it to interpret it as the byte sequence as in the first example.

How can this be achieved? It has to be ran on a server without File::Slurp.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first case, you pass the three bytes `AB CD EF` (produced by the string literal `"\xAB\xCD\xEF"`) to `print`.

In the second case, you must be passing something other than those three bytes to `print`. I suspect you are passing the twelve character string `\xAB\xCD\xEF` to `print`.

So your question becomes: How does one convert the twelve-character string `\xAB\xCD\xEF` into the three bytes `AB CD EF`. Well, you'd require some kind of parser such as

```
s/\\x([0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F])|\\([^x])|([^\\]+)/
   $1 ? chr(hex($1)) : $2 ? $2 : $3
/eg
```

And here it is at work:

```
$ perl -e'print "\\xAB\\xCD\\xEF";' >file

$ echo -n "$( perl -0777pe'
     s{\\x([0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F])|\\([^x])|([^\\]+)}{
        $1 ? chr(hex($1)) : $2 // $3
     }eg;
  ' file )" | od -t x1
0000000 ab cd ef
0000003
```

Comment: Sorry, the NUL byte was just me typing the dumbest example string ever. In my actual case there is no NUL byte.

Comment: @codd, I removed the NUL from your question, and I removed the corresponding comment from the my answer. I also fleshed out my explanation a bit.

Answer (score 0):

using a bash trick:

```
perl -e "$(echo "print \"$(cat input)"\")"
```

which for your example becomes:

```
./cprogram "$(perl -e "$(echo "print \"$(cat myfile.txt)"\")")"
```

Comment: ...wow, I just noticed that you expect the entire file to be hex escapes? If that's the case, my earlier comment doesn't apply, but I find that hard to believe that's the case.

Comment: Simpler? `./cprogram "$(perl -0777pe'$_=eval qq{"$_"}; die $@ if $@' myfile.txt )"`

Answer (score 0):

Is Perl's eval too evil? If not, end in `print eval("\"$file_contents\"");`

Or can you prepare the file in advance using Perl? EG `print FILE "\xAB\xCD\xED";` then read the resulting file with your existing code.